# Controlling M35SP-9T stepper with UNL2003

Tags: pi-2, wiring

I would like to control a recycled stepper motor with UNL2003.
I bought a downloaded a sample script from [here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/07/stepper-motor-control-in-python/)
Created a test circuit, and the controller is working fine with the 28BYJ motor.

I did my homework, found a few drawings, with this, or similar motors, but all of them was connected with 5 wires. The motor in the scanner was used with 4 wires (pin 1-2 and 4-5), the middle pin was not connected.

Of course, connecting to only 4 pins of the driver doesn't work. Can someome give me a hint, how to adapt a circuit like [this](http://www.cassianorabelo.com/_posted_images/2009-06-10-stepper-motor/circuito1.png) to a 4-wire solution?

Comment: A stepper motor with 4 wires will (most likely) be a 2 phase bipolar stepper motor. Look for tutorials on how to control this kind of stepper motor.

Comment: Thank you, now I could find that while it is possible to wire the UNL2003 to drive bipolar motors, it is probably the best for this project.